# sqflite no such table error while creating again a dropped table

Tags: sql, database, flutter, sqflite

I'm trying to create a local database in flutter and I'm using the sqflite library to tackle that. My database table needs to be dropped some times but the problem is whenever a table drops it cant be created again and it returns no such table error.

This is the error description:

```
[VERBOSE-2:ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: DatabaseException(Error Domain=FMDatabase Code=1 "no such table: foods" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=no such table: foods}) sql 'INSERT INTO foods (id, food_name, food_code, Name_of_home_units, Index_of_home_units) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)' args [1138, "Asian Salad", 9780102, ["gram"," spoon"], ["0","1"]]}
#0      wrapDatabaseException 
package:sqflite/src/exception_impl.dart:11
<asynchronous suspension>
#1      SqfliteDatabaseFactoryImpl.wrapDatabaseException 
package:sqflite/src/factory_impl.dart:78
#2      SqfliteDatabaseMixin.safeInvokeMethod 
package:sqflite_common/src/database_mixin.dart:208
#3      SqfliteDatabaseMixin.txnRawInsert.<anonymous closure> 
package:sqflite_common/src/database_mixin.dart:383
#4      SqfliteDatabaseMixin.txnSynchronized.<anonymous closure> 
package:sqflite_common/src/database_mixin.dart:327
#5      BasicLock.synchronized (package:synchronized/src/basic_lock.dart:3<…>
```

This is my database provider class:

```
class DatabaseProvider {
  Database _database;

  String TABLE_NAME = "foods";

  String COLUMN_ID = "id";
  String FOOD_NAME = "food_name";
  String FOOD_CODE = "food_code";
  String FOOD_UNITES = "Name_of_home_units";
  String FOOD_UNITES_INDEX = "Index_of_home_units";

  Future<Database> get database async {

    _database = await openDatabase(
      join(await getDatabasesPath(), 'doggie_database.db'),
      onCreate: (generatedDatabase, version){
        return generatedDatabase.execute("CREATE TABLE $TABLE_NAME"+
          "($COLUMN_ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," +
          "$FOOD_NAME TEXT," +
          "$FOOD_CODE TEXT," +
          "$FOOD_UNITES TEXT," +
          "$FOOD_UNITES_INDEX TEXT" +
          ")");
      },
      version: 1
    );
    return _database;
  }

  Future<Database> createDatabase() async {
    String dbPath = await getDatabasesPath();

      return openDatabase(
      join(await getDatabasesPath(), 'foodsDb.db'),
      onCreate: (generatedDatabase, version){
        return generatedDatabase.execute("CREATE TABLE $TABLE_NAME"+
          "($COLUMN_ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," +
          "$FOOD_NAME TEXT," +
          "$FOOD_CODE TEXT," +
          "$FOOD_UNITES TEXT," +
          "$FOOD_UNITES_INDEX TEXT" +
          ")");
      },
      version: 1
    );


  }


  Future<FoodItem> insertFood(FoodItem item) async {
    final db = await database;
    item.id = await db.insert("$TABLE_NAME", item.toMap());
    return item;
  }

  Future<List<Map<String, dynamic>>> getFoods() async {

    final db = await database;

    var foods = await db.query("$TABLE_NAME", columns: [
      COLUMN_ID,
      FOOD_NAME,
      FOOD_CODE,
      FOOD_UNITES,
      FOOD_UNITES_INDEX,
    ]);

    return foods;
  }

  Future<int> delete(int id) async {
    final db = await database;

    return await db.delete(
      "$TABLE_NAME",
      where: "id = ?",
      whereArgs: [id],
    );
  }

  Future<void> deleteWholeDatabase() async {

    final db = await database;

    db.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS $TABLE_NAME");

  }

  Future<int> update(FoodItem foodItem) async {
    final db = await database;

    return await db.update(
      "$TABLE_NAME",
      foodItem.toMap(),
      where: "id = ?",
      whereArgs: [foodItem.id],
    );
  }
}
```

I would be glad if you help me to tackle this problem. :)

Comment: insertFoods method is called after dropping table. so you are getting this.

Comment: @KedarKarki I want to add foods after dropping the table; my adding food flow is like this 1.drop previous table, 2. create the database table, 3. insert food. is it wrong??